# Import Error Pythonnet Window 10

Tags: python, .net, conda, importerror, python.net

#### Environment

1. Pythonnet version: 2.4.0.dev0, installed from Master
2. Python version: Python 3.6.6, Anaconda 3
3. Operating System: Window 10, 64 bit
4. Using virtual studio 2017 Community

#### Details

I had virtual environment set up.

1) pip list

```
(py36) C:\Users\User\Desktop>pip list
Package         Version
--------------- ----------
certifi         2018.8.13
click           6.7
cycler          0.10.0
kiwisolver      1.0.1
matplotlib      2.2.3
mkl-fft         1.0.4
mkl-random      1.0.1
numpy           1.15.0
Pillow          5.2.0
pip             18.0
pyparsing       2.2.0
PyQt5           5.11.2
PyQt5-sip       4.19.12
python-dateutil 2.7.3
pythonnet       2.4.0.dev0
pytz            2018.5
scipy           1.1.0
setuptools      40.0.0
six             1.11.0
visbrain        0.4.2
vispy           0.5.3
wheel           0.31.1
wincertstore    0.2
```

2) path and pythonpath before python initialize.

```
string path = @"D:\Anaconda3\envs\py36;" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", @"D:\Anaconda3\envs\py36", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process); 

// initialize python engine
PythonEngine.Initialize();
```

3) set Amaconda in %PATH%

[image: My Path]

4) python path

```
(py36) C:\Users\User\Desktop>python --version
Python 3.6.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

ReadMe works fine.

but when i typed like this in my C# program

```
using (Py.GIL())
{
     // import vispy
     dynamic myVispy = Py.Import("vispy");
     Console.WriteLine("hi vispy");
}
```

error message below
`Python.Runtime.PythonException: 'ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'vispy''`

stack trace :

```
 Python.Runtime.PythonException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'vispy'
  Source=Python.Runtime
  StackTrace:
```

would like to know how to solve this ?
Thank You.

Comment: The third step looks wrong. Why would you set the root Anaconda environment into `%PATH%`?! Are you not using "py36" environment.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63605963/8298327): Python.NET does not work with Anaconda or Miniconda. You need a fresh python install.